# Eclipse's "extract to method" on Function results in compilation error

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

Starting with a class `A` with 2 fields, `name` and `id`, a constructor and getters, I wrote this test, which runs green:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    List<A> list = Arrays.asList(new A(null, "a"), new A(null, "b"));

    Collections.sort(list,
            Comparator
            .comparing(A::getName, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
            .thenComparing(A::getId, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.reverseOrder())));

    assertThat(list.get(0).id, is("b"));
}
```

However, if I select Eclipse's quick fix "extract to method" on `A::getName`:

[image: extract to method]

I suddenly get 2 compilation errors on the next line (`thenComparing(...)`):

```
@Test
public void test() {
    List<A> list = Arrays.asList(new A(null, "a"), new A(null, "b"));

    Collections.sort(list,
            Comparator
            .comparing(extracted(), Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
            .thenComparing(A::getId, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.reverseOrder())));

    assertThat(list.get(0).id, is("b"));
}

private Function<? super A, ? extends String> extracted() {
    return A::getName;
}
```

Saying:

> The type Test.A does not define getId(capture#1-of ? super Test.A) that is applicable here

and

> The method thenComparing(Function<? super capture#1-of ? super Test.A,? extends U>, Comparator<? super U>) in the type Comparator is not applicable for the arguments (A::getId, Comparator<Comparable<? super Comparable<? super T>>>)

Why does this result in an error? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems to be a problem with Eclipse’s type inference (works with `javac`). Nevertheless, there is no benefit in wildcards in return types, so you should declare `private Function<A, String> extracted() { return A::getName; }` anyway. That should solve your problem.

Comment: Now that we established that the compile error is reported for good reasons, has anyone filed a bug regarding the refactoring, viz. to request that this refactoring fail during precondition checks?

Answer (score 0):

It's the refactoring that's to blame. It creates two new wildcards that need to be captured before / during type inference. After this, types can no longer be unified and inference cannot find a solution.

Another bug is that javac 8 accepted this code, but this has been fixed in javac 9 (I tried build 9-ea+118).

In that version javac's error message reads:

```
error: no suitable method found for thenComparing(A::getId,Comparator<T#1>)
          .thenComparing(A::getId, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.reverseOrder())));
          ^
method Comparator.<U#1>thenComparing(Function<? super CAP#1,? extends U#1>,Comparator<? super U#1>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) U#1
    (argument mismatch; invalid method reference
      method getId in class A cannot be applied to given types
        required: no arguments
        found: CAP#1
        reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
method Comparator.<U#2>thenComparing(Function<? super CAP#1,? extends U#2>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) U#2
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
where T#1,T#2,U#1,T#3,U#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends T#2
    T#2 extends Comparable<? super T#2>
    U#1 extends Object declared in method <U#1>thenComparing(Function<? super T#3,? extends U#1>,Comparator<? super U#1>)
    T#3 extends Object declared in interface Comparator
    U#2 extends Comparable<? super U#2> declared in method <U#2>thenComparing(Function<? super T#3,? extends U#2>)
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object super: A from capture of ? super A
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
```

**EDIT:**
The bug in javac was most likely https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8039214 which was indeed resolved for version 9. This is said to be the "master bug" for a cluster of related bugs dealing with javac's failure to correctly handle wildcard captures. In that bug the following text is proposed for the release notes:

> The javac compiler's behavior when handling wildcards and "capture" type variables has been improved for conformance to the language specification. This improves type checking behavior in certain unusual circumstances. It is also a source-incompatible change: certain uses of wildcards that have compiled in the past may fail to compile because of a program's reliance on the javac bug.

<strike>I believe in both cases (javac 9 and ecj) the complaint regarding `getId` is secondary, result of inference having failed already.</strike>

At a closer look, the error against `getId` is the primary cause for failure to type-check:

- The resolved type of `comparing(..)` is `Comparator<capture#1-of ? super A>` (capture induced by capturing the resolved type of `extracted()`).
- The target type for the method reference `A::getName` is `Function<? super capture#1-of ? super A,? extends U>` (from the first parameter of `<U> Comparator<T> thenComparing(Function<? super T, ? extends U>, Comparator<? super U>)`
- The non-wildcard parameterization ([JLS 9.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.9)) of this target type is `<capture#1-of ? super A, U>`.
- Hence the method reference must implement the function type `U apply(capture#1-of ? super A)`
- To use the argument of `apply` as the receiver for `getId` we need a value of type `A`, but we only have guarantees that the provided value is a (unknown) super type of `A`.
- javac reverts to expecting an argument of the given type, while `getId` takes no argument -> hence the 1st message regarding argument list lengths.
- Ergo `getId` does not implement the expected functional type.

This vaguely matches the description in JDK-8039214 that javac 8 erroneously uses a bound of the capture, instead of the capture itself. I say vaguely, because the bug speaks of upper bounds, while here javac 8 seems to use a lower bound even.

Comment: How can the complaint regarding `getId` be secondary, if it is *the only one*, e.g. replacing `A::getId` with `null` makes all compiler errors go away?

Comment: @Holger the main message is that inference for `thenComparing` failed. Additionally, ecj reports "... does not define getId(...) that is applicable here" and javac mentions "...method getId in class A cannot be applied to given types...". These messages I consider secondary. Of course any change inside that big expression can influence inference and possibly cause it to succeed. Still the event to report is: inference could not find a solution for the invocation of `thenComparing`.

Comment: I don’t see anything near “*could not find a solution*” in the message. I see something like “*actual and formal argument lists differ in length*”, which is so nonsensical regarding the situation, that considering this to be a hint about a more correct working compiler, is questionable. But anyway, there are two messages and there is no indicator that one of them is “secondary”.

Comment: @Holger: javac 9 at the top of the message says: "_cannot infer type-variable(s)..._". How is this different from inference not finding a solution? I don't see what you are aiming at. OTOH, arity mismatch is mentioned only to show why the 1-arg overload of `thenComparing` is ruled out. Makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: @Holder, apologies for a wrong guess about secondary vs. primary error. Indeed type checking for `getId` yields the root cause for rejecting the code. I also failed to see that "_actual and formal argument lists differ in length_" is mentioned twice in javac's error messages. I've updated the answer to explain why `A::getId` doesn't match the target type, including a hint, why a compiler may complain about argument list lengths also here.

Comment: As soon as more people try javac version 9 I expect to see more questions on SO to ask why code valid for javac 8 is no longer accepted. OTOH, I'm very happy about the fix for the mentioned JDK bug, because it significantly reduces the differences between compilers. More like this is still pending, see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8016207

Comment: This can’t be related to JDK-8039214 as JDK9 versions much older than the fix already show this behavior. Actually I don’t see any indicator for this being an intentional behavior at all. It might be in line with the current JLS, but in the end there is no need for JDK9 to adhere to the current JLS, but only to the not-yet-released JLS9. Don’t be surprised, if the JLS gets changed, just to avoid the sudden rejection of these not semantically wrong cases…

Comment: I mentioned that JDK-8039214 is an umbrella in a network of bugs linked to each other. Perhaps the particular issue was fixed via  https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8033718 (released for build b13). I don't have all intermediate builds of javac to identify which one brought the fix. Do you? Anyway I know that the JDK9 development cycle is being actively used for fixing bugs that were known already during the previous cycle, i.e., bugs that are reported wrt JLS 8. Dan is usually careful to consider changing javac or JLS, in this case he decided for the former, for good reasons I'm sure.